# What language do the minions speak?

Tags: dialogue, despicable-me

In *Despicable Me*, what language(s) do the minions speak? There is a bit of English, but it seems like a combination of French with English?

Comment: They also say some words in spanish, like: "Es para tu" (even though it should be "es para ti")

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [**Despicable Me - Creating The Minions**](http://www.femalefirst.co.uk/movies/Despicable+Me+Creating+The+Minions-9217.html):

> The [directors] subsequently designed a language for Gru’s army that **is intended to be an indescribable vocal expression**
>
> ***"The language is much more about sound than it is about any kind of meaning,"*** says [producer] Christopher Meledandri.

[Here you can watch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9903d4hE5k) a short featurette where producer *John Cohen* explains:

> *The voices of the minions are actually done by* Pierre Coffin *and* Chris Renaud, *the directors of the movie.*
>
> *And what they have done is ... created this incredibly unique language. **A lot of times it sounds like it’s gibberish, a lot of times you hear a little bit of french. You hear all kinds of languages being incorporated into the way they speak.***
>
> ***And then occasionally, you hear a word or two of English, or that sounds like English, that gives you a sense of what the minions are actually saying.***

Comment: I am wondering if the dialogs are somehow "translated" in versions of the movies localized for other language audiences. I happened to watch the movies in Japanese, and could catch some English/French/Spanish/Italian... sounding bits.

Comment: Some words were 'translated' in the localised version od the first movie from the series that I was watching.